# Itunes connect binary update mobile version alone

Tags: app-store-connect

I have an app in app store with watch extension. Now i want update mobile version alone.

Do Apple allow to upload mobile version alone? Or i have to upload with watch app?

Please advise me.

Thanks in advance,
Dragon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to upload with your watch app.

Ex.

iOS App: ver 1.0.0
Watch App: ver 1.0.0

-> update

iOS App: ver 1.1.0
Watch App: ver 1.1.0

iOS App and Watch App must be same version.